# updateOrCreate() is not working in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

I have a table named hierarchies as follows:
     [image]
`$reformedSubordinates` is an array of `user_id`. Now I want to insert new entry or update if exist as follows:

```
  foreach($reformedSubordinates as $user_id) {

              Hierarchy::updateOrCreate(
                ['up' => $loggedInUserId, 'down' => $user_id],
                ['status' => 1]
            );
          }
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'status' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `hierarchies` (`up`, `down`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, 2, 2019-07-02 05:18:02, 2019-07-02 05:18:02))
```

Whats wrong in my code? any idea?

Answer (score 0):

i think it should be like this:

```
foreach($reformedSubordinates as $user_id) {

          Hierarchy::updateOrCreate(
            ['up' => $loggedInUserId, 'down' => $user_id ,'status' => 1],
            ['status' => 1]
        );
      }
```

Comment: because status not null when create you should insert status

Answer (score 0):

Please Check in user Model **Hierarchy** you added status in **$fillable** or Not

if not then that is your problem you have to added it

or you can use  **$guarded**